# Get emails which were sent with php mail

Tags: php, sql-server

Is there a way to check the emails which were sent by php script ?

I have a php script which send email upon registration. and somebody says it did not sent him the email. I tested myself and script sent me an email, i think it is working, however i want to check it. I just want to check if my server sent him a email. Is there any options to check the last emails to which my server sent an email ?
the php script use mail() function

Comment: Like bondye said, check logs...

Comment: This might help if you're using Linux: http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-log-emails-sent-with-phps-mail-function-to-detect-form-spam

Comment: How do you expect to verify whether an e-mail left your server and then got lost on the way, got blocked as spam on their side, went into their junk mail folder, etc.? Mail is terribly unreliable and it is very cumbersome to prove where it went wrong - especially if he is pointing fingers at you.

Comment: how to check logs, post an answer

Comment: @Jigberto That **completely** depends on your mail server.  Contact your friendly local sysadmin.